# How to calculate the maximum supported value of a signed bit-field?

Tags: c, c99, bit-fields, c11

Suppose my project includes a header from a 3rd party library that contains this:

```
struct foo {
    signed int x:4;
};
```

Without assuming that the bit-field will always have width 4, and without relying on implementation-defined behavior, how can I determine the maximum value that can be stored in member `x`?

Comment: reliably you can store only `1111`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: "Without assuming that the bit-field will always have width 4."  The 3rd party developer might change the width to 5 in the next version.  Or 13.  Or something else.  I don't want my code to break when the width of the bit-field changes.

Comment: I didn't get :( , *`Without assuming that the bit-field will always have width 4`* it will always have 4-with with any compiler... am I missing something?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:  That 4 might change to a 5 or something else in the next version of the 3rd party library.

Comment: Ok got it! now ..good question. But :( no idea, I feel only you can know about this from third party library docs. but How to build a stable code?? still a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't. The issue is the same as for determining `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`: because you can't determine these yourself, the compiler implementation *has to* provide these values. (All you could do to determine the position of the sign bit has implementation defined (or even undefined) behavior: overflow, shift operators)

For bitfields the implementation can't provide these values, so you are stuck.

This is one of the reasons bitfields really shouldn't be `signed`. Bitfields are for bit manipulations and nothing else, the sign bit is then just wasted.

If your field would be `unsigned` things would be easy. You'd just have to store `-1` in it and you'd get the value with all ones, the maximum value for the "type".

Answer (score 5):

Since size of a bitfield it can't be calculated with `sizeof`, this can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    signed int x: 4;
};

#define BIT(n) (1l << (n))
#define BIT_MASK(len) (BIT(len) - 1)

int main(void)
{
    struct foo f = {0};
    long i = 0;

    while (f.x >= 0) {
        f.x = BIT_MASK(++i);
    }
    printf("bits=%ld max=%ld\n", i, BIT_MASK(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Left shift until `f.x` is negative.

**EDIT:**

The above code  is implementation-defined, check this one, I think this will work (but you have to deal with BIG ENDIAN):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct foo {
    signed int x: 4;
};

#define BIT(n) (1l << (n))
#define BIT_MASK(len) (BIT(len) - 1)

int main(void)
{
    long x, i = 0;
    struct foo f;

    f.x = -1;
    memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof(f));
    while (1) {
        if (!(x & BIT(++i))) break; 
    }
    printf("bits=%ld max=%ld\n", i, BIT_MASK(i));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see now it doesn't exceeds *2^(n-1)-1* (works on a `long`)

Comment: this is very good answer! David RF you should add some comments and explanation.

Comment: OP (@Richard Hansen): Check this code working @[codepad](http://codepad.org/aWKoshW3)

Comment: I believe this relies on implementation-defined behavior.  Once `BIT_MASK(++i)` exceeds 2^3-1, the value is outside the range of representable values.  C99 6.3.1.3p3 says that if the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it, either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  Thus, I can't portably rely on the value going negative (and it could theoretically crash, although I'm unaware of any implementation that would).

Comment: @DavidRF:  Unfortunately there's still implementation-defined (or undefined) behavior:  `sizeof(f)` might be greater than `sizeof(x)` (see C99 6.7.2.1p15), the other bits in `f` might not be 0 (C99 6.2.6.1p6, and I can't find what the standard says about the value of the leftover bits in the byte(s) holding the bit field), the order of the bits in the bit field's representation is implementation-defined (e.g., the sign bit might be in the middle of the value bits), and the order of allocation of the bits within the containing byte(s) is implementation-defined (C99 6.7.2.1p11).

Comment: @RichardHansen, does `#pragma pack` helps here? hope you find a solution

Comment: No, the behavior of `#pragma pack` is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would have tried loading a -1 to it and if it is a 2's complement representation then it would be the maximum positive value that can be stored.
Above case

foo.x = -1;
unsigned int max_size = (unsigned int)(foo.x);

half of it will be unsigned max, half+1 will be the signed max